# Warning in invalid property name when AOT compiling an Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I'm getting the following warning (in bold letters) when I build an Angular 5 application for production, using the command `ng build --prod --aot`:

> chunk {0} 0.aa2387338203eacb7219.chunk.js () 1.29 MB  [rendered] chunk
>   {1} 1.c31031b3e6618b7c9542.chunk.js () 4.18 kB  [rendered] chunk {2}
>   main.5eaed2e0f72790b03842.bundle.js (main) 1.09 MB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {3} polyfills.bf4704f800e5ab645c1f.bundle.js
>   (polyfills) 64.4 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {4}
>   styles.5df91b5161602f93c89e.bundle.css (styles) 604 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {5} inline.0e45b8ea479f1b119f7c.bundle.js (inline)
>   1.42 kB [entry] [rendered]
>
> **WARNING in Invalid property name '        filter' at 6347:4. Ignoring.**

The application runs fine despite the warning, but I'd like to know the reason of it, because I've searched all my components and there aren't any with a property named `filter`. Perhaps it belongs to a third party component I'm using?

Thanks,

Comment: could probably be a third-party lib; do you use array.filter somewhere in your code? can you post your tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from a third party component I use in the app. If I don't use it, the compilation ends without any error or warning. I've posted a question to the component developer to see if they have detected this issue before.

Cheers,